# Sharing info between Android phones

Tags: android

This is my first non school related Android question. Me and a friend are making a game, only I am not sure where to start with the communication between devices. They won't be sending much information between them, just enough for a few variables to see who wins. I've seen a few different ways to do this, but I'm not sure where to start. How would I send the info to and fro?

Comment: This question is fairly broad, but generally speaking, network sockets. Be that Bluetooth, WiFi, or mobile Internet, that's up to you.

Comment: I understand that, I have just never worked with any type of code to send the data between devices. I would preferably want to start with wifi. I assume it's the easiest to start with.

Comment: Easy is relative...  There are many Chat example apps out there. Firebase and Socket.io are good ones. Google has source code for a Bluetooth Chat. http://developer.android.com/samples/BluetoothChat/index.html